# Convert to get endOffset for each element

Tags: javascript

im using a function(at the end) from Tim(rangy library) to get the range starting and ending offset of a paragraph, the problem is that its only getting the TOTAL characters as end

example:

```
<p id="p1">testing 1</p>
<p id="p2">testing 2</p>
<p id="p3">testing 3</p>
```

selecting test (from p1), it correctly returns 0,4 (start,end)

if i select `testing 1`, and `testing` from p2 and use:

```
getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(#p1); //0,16
getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(#p2); //0,16
```

how can i set it to just catch the end offset for the given element? is there a way to do that?
i understand that its setting end by this function:                 `end = preCaretRange.toString().length;` as  the selected text size, but how to limit to the given element?

function below:

```
function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    start = 0;
    end = 0;
    doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    }
    return { start: start, end: end };
```